# Reference secret from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Currently, as I see it, there istwo ways of referencing secrets:

1. by using @ `@Microsoft.KeyVault(...)`, or
2. directly, having fx a secret named secret in the vault, and then reference it directly

For 2) i have this extra in my Program.cs

```
 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
             {
                 //Only for use when running in a VM, else remove this
                 var builtConfig = config.Build();
                 var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                 var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                     new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                         azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                 config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                     $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                     keyVaultClient,
                     new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
             })
```

When do I use what? Is the @ notation for use when you either:

1. have an Azure Function, or
2. a configuring an already running application, and adding a Key Vault to the stack

I have a hard time seeing when to use what.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to fully get your question , anyway for what I knoe the syntax @Microsoft.KeyVault(...) is designed to be used on app service configuration blade ( function app is also considered an app service ) , instead if you are using your code that depends on the sdk that you are using

Comment: I have a hard time seeing what is the recommended way of using it. By code only I always get latest version, but that isn't possible with @ notation. I also know that it is only on new versions of azure function sdk that I can use the code first way. On older versions I can only use @, I think.

Comment: I tried to use the @ notation in this way @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret) without the secret version and seems to work well .

For the sdk, to which sdk are you referring to ?

Comment: That is not an official way of doing it. It is more of a hack. Microsoft has refused to put it in the docs. I have working code on both asp.net core 3.1 and azure functions v3. I can't see why I shouldn't use the native code first instead of supplying secrets through environment variables.

Comment: I created a PR and an issue suggesting to put that into the documentationhttps://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/63304 .

Environment variables are usually more dynamic , if you want to change the secret name later you can without impact your code .
Also use native code first is a total valid approach in my view

Comment: I read another issue where they went to update the docs, but after the author consulted with a technician they stopped it again. I can't remember the issue id. I am wat hing yours now :)